# How should I work around the context object for DI and testing?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-context

I have a class that creates a bitmap object.

It needs access to a bitmap resource so it needs access to the context which I pass into its constructor so I call it like **myClass(context)**

Ideally i'd like to inject the dependency somehow. I wanted to do this with a factory so I could just ask the factory for the object and it creates it for me, but I can only get context from activity classes which create new windows. So it seems I'll have to keep passing in context from my main activity.

I asked a similar question recently and was told I shouldnt call context statically at all and should always be passing it around.

This means if I want to test this class my test class needs access to the android framework (which means I can't test locally and will have to use AndroidTests).

Is this how it is supposed to work? My class just needs a bitmap but I can't test locally now because of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the functionality of `Context`, then you'll need to pass it into `MyClass` one way or another. However, this doesn't mean that you need to statically store `Context`. In fact, that would be a really bad design choice (looks like you already know that).

If you use Dagger, then I have [this video](https://youtu.be/cx6pCIbOqtI) tutorial that explains how to structure dependency injection code. Part of this structuring is indeed handling the complexity of `Context` objects.

Now, even if `MyClass` needs an access to `Context` in order to obtain bitmap, it doesn't necessarily mean that you need resolve to integration tests.

First of all, you can use Robolectric - this library "mocks" Android framework, and I think that it supports getting bitmap from resources.

However, depending on your use case, there is also a simpler option. Do you really need a specific bitmap, or you just want to ensure that `MyClass` performs specific actions on this bitmap?

If you need the specific one that you add as a resource then go for Robolectric, but if not and all you need is to make sure that the obtained bitmap is being used correctly then you can just mock the bitmap.

In order to increase readability, simplify the testing and prevent violation of Law of Demeter, I suggest that you wrap `Context` into this class:

```
public class BitmapRetriever {
    private final Context mContext;

    public BitmapRetriever(Context context) { 
        mContext = context;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapById(int id) {
        // code that obtains bitmap
    }
}
```

Then make `MyClass` depend on `BitmapRetriever` instead of `Context`.

Once you do this, it will be straightforward to pass mocked `BitmapRetriever` in test that will return mocked `Bitmap` when `MyClass` asks for it. Then you can assert various conditions on that mock.

Comment: That interesting, but how does having a separate bitmap retriever make testing easier.

Comment: @red888, it gets down to Single Responsibility Principle. If your class takes in Context, then it can theoretically access all its methods. You know that it uses just one of them, but the guy who will work after you (or you yourself six months from now) will not know this. Furthermore, passing Context into any class breaks encapsulation. By wrapping it into a class that do has one single responsibility, you make it simpler to read the code and write tests, and you eliminate possibility that in the future someone will start using other Context's methods too.

Comment: @red888, in short - if your class needs just bitmap, there is no reason to get it access the entire Context. It is called Law of Demeter violation.

Comment: @red888, more about single responsibility principle and context here: https://www.techyourchance.com/single-responsibility-principle/

Comment: If I build myClass with a factory, would I still be passing context to the factory that creates the object? I guess I would have to because I can't make the factory an activity class right? Also, why are you using "final" in the context wrapper?

Comment: @red888, passing `Context` to a factory is alright because, by definition, factory is a wrapper and has only one responsibility - to instantiate one kind of objects. Finalizing members of a class that aren't supposed to change is best practice that I follow.

Answer (score 1):

If your class only needs a bitmap, why can't you **mock** a bitmap? You should test the logic in your class. You do not need to test the `Context` bitmap loading functionality as I'm sure that is already tested in the Android framework. You already have a great idea with the *factory pattern* as you could just inject a mock factory for testing by using `myClass(bitmapFactory)` in your app and `myClass(mockFactory)` in your tests.

If you're absolutely sure you need to write a test to cover the bitmap loading, then look into testing frameworks like [robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) as it can provide **mock context** for scenarios like this.